# Check if key exists and iterate the JSON array using Python

Tags: python, json, loops

I have a bunch of JSON data from Facebook posts like the one below:

```
{"from": {"id": "8", "name": "Mary Pinter"}, "message": "How ARE you?", "comments": {"count": 0}, "updated_time": "2012-05-01", "created_time": "2012-05-01", "to": {"data": [{"id": "1543", "name": "Honey Pinter"}]}, "type": "status", "id": "id_7"}
```

The JSON data is semi-structured and all is not the same. 
Below is my code:

```
import json 

str = '{"from": {"id": "8", "name": "Mary Pinter"}, "message": "How ARE you?", "comments": {"count": 0}, "updated_time": "2012-05-01", "created_time": "2012-05-01", "to": {"data": [{"id": "1543", "name": "Honey Pinter"}]}, "type": "status", "id": "id_7"}'
data = json.loads(str)

post_id = data['id']
post_type = data['type']
print(post_id)
print(post_type)

created_time = data['created_time']
updated_time = data['updated_time']
print(created_time)
print(updated_time)

if data.get('application'):
    app_id = data['application'].get('id', 0)
    print(app_id)
else:
    print('null')

#if data.get('to'):
#... This is the part I am not sure how to do
# Since it is in the form "to": {"data":[{"id":...}]}
```

I want the code to print the *to_id* as 1543 else print 'null'

I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 215):

```
import json

jsonData = """{"from": {"id": "8", "name": "Mary Pinter"}, "message": "How ARE you?", "comments": {"count": 0}, "updated_time": "2012-05-01", "created_time": "2012-05-01", "to": {"data": [{"id": "1543", "name": "Honey Pinter"}]}, "type": "status", "id": "id_7"}"""

def getTargetIds(jsonData):
    data = json.loads(jsonData)
    if 'to' not in data:
        raise ValueError("No target in given data")
    if 'data' not in data['to']:
        raise ValueError("No data for target")

    for dest in data['to']['data']:
        if 'id' not in dest:
            continue
        targetId = dest['id']
        print("to_id:", targetId)
```

Output:

```
In [9]: getTargetIds(s)
to_id: 1543
```

Comment: Why do this explicit `in` checks and `raise` if they're missing? Just access it without checking, and you'll get exactly the same behavior (except with a `KeyError` instead of a `ValueError`).

Comment: @abarnert because the question is about checking if a key exists or not. There might be something other than raising errors that OP wants to do.

Answer (score 154):

If all you want is to check if key exists or not

```
h = {'a': 1}
'b' in h # returns False
```

If you want to check if there is a value for key

```
h.get('b') # returns None
```

Return a default value if actual value is missing

```
h.get('b', 'Default value')
```

Comment: will return 'null' and not 'Default value' as expected for b in case of {'a':1, 'b':null}

Answer (score 26):

It is a good practice to create helper utility methods for things like that so that whenever you need to change the logic of attribute validation it would be in one place, and the code will be more readable for the followers.

For example create a helper method (or class `JsonUtils` with static methods) in `json_utils.py`:

```
def get_attribute(data, attribute, default_value):
    return data.get(attribute) or default_value
```

and then use it in your project:

```
from json_utils import get_attribute

def my_cool_iteration_func(data):

    data_to = get_attribute(data, 'to', None)
    if not data_to:
        return

    data_to_data = get_attribute(data_to, 'data', [])
    for item in data_to_data:
        print('The id is: %s' % get_attribute(item, 'id', 'null'))
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

There is a reason I am using `data.get(attribute) or default_value` instead of simply `data.get(attribute, default_value)`:

```
{'my_key': None}.get('my_key', 'nothing') # returns None
{'my_key': None}.get('my_key') or 'nothing' # returns 'nothing'
```

In my applications getting attribute with value 'null' is the same as not getting the attribute at all. If your usage is different, you need to change this.

Comment: This expression really helped, couldn't find it elsewhere... Lol. Thanks 5 years later! `data.get(attribute) or default_value` in this case is the same as `data[attribute]`, but doesn't throw KeyError if the key doesn't exist. Very handy! :)

Answer (score 19):

```
if "my_data" in my_json_data:
         print json.dumps(my_json_data["my_data"])
```

Comment: This one is not a good "checker" because you can have a key "my_data_whateverasdasdalfhskjhsad" and this still will return True because of the substring "my_data"...

Comment: @Igoranze How so? That's not the case when I tested. Since the comment is 3 years old; was this true then, and later changed?

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a tiny function for this purpose. Feel free to repurpose,

```
def is_json_key_present(json, key):
    try:
        buf = json[key]
    except KeyError:
        return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 4):

```
jsonData = """{"from": {"id": "8", "name": "Mary Pinter"}, "message": "How ARE you?", "comments": {"count": 0}, "updated_time": "2012-05-01", "created_time": "2012-05-01", "to": {"data": [{"id": "1543", "name": "Honey Pinter"}, {"name": "Joe Schmoe"}]}, "type": "status", "id": "id_7"}"""

def getTargetIds(jsonData):
    data = json.loads(jsonData)
    for dest in data['to']['data']:
        print("to_id:", dest.get('id', 'null'))
```

Try it:

```
>>> getTargetIds(jsonData)
to_id: 1543
to_id: null
```

Or, if you just want to skip over values missing ids instead of printing `'null'`:

```
def getTargetIds(jsonData):
    data = json.loads(jsonData)
    for dest in data['to']['data']:
        if 'id' in to_id:
            print("to_id:", dest['id'])
```

So:

```
>>> getTargetIds(jsonData)
to_id: 1543
```

Of course in real life, you probably don't want to `print` each id, but to store them and do something with them, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 3):

**You can use a try-except**

```
try:
   print(str.to.id)
except AttributeError: # Not a Retweet
   print('null')
```