# How to return empty string if property doesn't exist in the JSON string?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON string from which I am trying to extract a property value using Python as shown below:

```
def extract_property(node, to_extract):
    data, stat = zk.get(node)
    jsonString = data.decode("utf-8")
    jStr = json.loads(jsonString)
    return jStr[to_extract]
```

Now it is possible, the property value that I am trying to extract doesn't exist in that JSON string so it will fail. How can I return empty string if property doesn't exist at all in the JSON string.

This line can fail if property doesn't exist.

```
return jStr[to_extract]
```

Comment: `if to_extract in jStr:`

Comment: Couldn't you just go `if jStr[to_extract]: return jStr[to_extract] else: return None`

Comment: @MooingRawr That will get the same error if the property doesn't exist.

Comment: @barmar I see, learn something new everyday, For some reason I thought JSON objects are special and would return nothing if they couldn't find the property. Thinking about it now, that seems rather silly.

Comment: @MooingRawr There's no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is a string representation of data structures. After you decode it, it's just a native data type. In this case, it's a Python dictionary.

Comment: Another related and possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898797/check-if-key-exists-and-iterate-the-json-array-using-python

Comment: @Barmar **Not** a duplicate of any `dict`-specific question, for reasons made clear in the OP-accepted answer.

Comment: @jez Since he's trying to access a specific property as if it's a `dict`, I think the assumption that the JSON is known a priori to be an object is reasonable. It's only the property name that's dynamic.

Comment: @Barmar same syntax could be for accessing a sequence element, rather than a dict element, and the fact that the OP said it "didn't work for me" ***until*** this was taken into account in the answer, indicates that this was in fact the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `dict.get()`, i.e.:

```
return jStr.get(to_extract, '')
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get for more details.

UPD:

Thanks to @jez for pointing out, that `jStr` is not guaranteed to be a dictionary. However, the result for JSON parsing is known: if it's not a dictionary, then it's a list, number or a string. In this case, wrap it into a type checking routine, e.g.:

```
try:
    return jStr[to_extract]
except (KeyError, AttributeError):
    return ''
```

Comment: What this will do? Can you explain a bit for my understanding?

Comment: the linked doc seems pretty straightforward

Comment: Is this Python 3 feature? It doesn't work for me at all. I am on 2.7.3 and cannot upgrade.

Comment: No, this has been there since beginning of time.

Answer (score 1):

Like Zaur, I would also have suggested `jStr.get(to_extract, '')` but I presume the OP's objection to this is that `jStr` might *or might not be* a `dict`  (if it is a `dict`, then `.get()` will work in Python 2 or 3).  If that's the problem, then the following might cover a broader range of cases:

```
try: return jStr[to_extract]
except: return ''
```