# (if exists) get an element from a structured JSON with Python 3.6

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43941564/1008588) answer I understand that I can use the GET instruction to catch an element of a JSON file and get a `None` if this does not exists. But I can't understand how to use with more than one level of JSON data.

Let's have a look at the following example:

```
import json
json_input = '{"persons": [{"name": "Brian", "city": "Seattle"}, {"name": "David", "city": "Amsterdam"} ] }'
d = json.loads(json_input)
```

- Input `d.get('persons')` output

> [{'name': 'Brian', 'city': 'Seattle'}, {'name': 'David',
>   'city':'Amsterdam'}]

- Input `d.get('animals')` output

> None

but I would like to use the same to check if `d['persons'][0]['name']` exist, or if `d['persons'][0]['tel_number']`.
If I use `d.get(['persons'][0]['name'])` I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       d.get(['persons'][0]['name']) TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Who downvoted my question could explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct approach would be this:

`d.get('persons')[0].get('name')`

`get()` applied on dictionary returns value of given key, if possible. Then we access list inside it and try to `get()` value of key called `name` again.

This can raise `IndexError` or `KeyError` exceptions if there's no list or no `persons` or `name` key, but you can handle this with `try .. except` block as outlined in iBug's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a valid solution:

```
def myGet(d, k1, k2, k3):
    try:
        return d[k1][k2][k3]
    except (TypeError, IndexError, KeyError):
        return None

asdfg = myGet(d, 'persons', 0, 'name')
```

You got the TypeError because Python treated `['persons']` as a list containing one string, instead of an index, so `['persons'][0]` gets to `'persons'`, which cannot be indexed by another string.

Comment: The function you posted works but I don't find it useful. I would find useful something like myGet(d['persons'][0]['name']) that output 'Brian' and myGet(d['persons'][0]['abc']) that output 'None'.

Comment: @Nicolaesse You of course can add another parameter to the function that's used in the third index. Like I just updated the answer.