# Cannot parse SQS Json response

Tags: python, json, boto3, amazon-sqs

I have created a consumer to gather bounces and complaints in an SQS Queue. It is working for the majority of my messages, but there are some messages coming in that are throwing an Exception.

The JSON output that works:

```
{"notificationType":"Complaint","complaint":{"feedbackId":"0100018217177664-7d73c160-0be8-49aa-b9c4-bd1d1aebd362-000000","complaintSubType":null,"complainedRecipients":[{"emailAddress":"some-email-addres@yahoo.com"}],"timestamp":"2022-07-19T15:33:09.000Z","userAgent":"Yahoo!-Mail-Feedback/2.0","complaintFeedbackType":"abuse","arrivalDate":"2022-07-08T12:58:35.000Z"},"mail":{"timestamp":"2022-07-08T12:58:34.633Z","source":"noreply@example.com","sourceArn":"arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:669689702539:identity/example.com","sourceIp":"12.34.56.789","callerIdentity":"ses-smtp-user.20190509-104648","sendingAccountId":"1234567890","messageId":"01000181dde3fb09-77fa66a7-6425-4a17-974c-5b49c8ab930d-000000","destination":["some-email@yahoo.com"],"headersTruncated":false,"headers":[{"name":"Received","value":"from mail-aws-va-1 ([12.34.56.789]) by email-smtp.amazonaws.com with SMTP (SimpleEmailService-d-9BN0NGUJI) id MfVVhu8nS86Hc4osVk6w for some-email@yahoo.com; Fri, 08 Jul 2022 12:58:34 +0000 (UTC)"},{"name":"Received","value":"by mail-aws-va-1 (Postfix, from userid 111) id E1DA561FD2; Fri,  8 Jul 2022 07:57:50 -0500 (CDT)"},{"name":"Received","value":"from localhost.localdomain (some-server [192.168.20.2]) by mail-aws-va-1 (Postfix) with ESMTP id E5776621E0 for <some-email@yahoo.com>; Fri,  8 Jul 2022 07:57:16 -0500 (CDT)"},{"name":"Date","value":"Fri, 8 Jul 2022 07:57:16 -0500"},{"name":"To","value":"some-email@yahoo.com"},{"name":"From","value":"\"Some Gift Shop Inc.\" <noreply@example.com>"},{"name":"Reply-to","value":"\"Some Gift Shop Inc.\" <blahblahblah@some-email.com>"},{"name":"Subject","value":"Some Subject"},{"name":"Message-ID","value":"<9d6ba9128d45561e70b162efc7b6b1b2@localhost.localdomain>"},{"name":"X-Priority","value":"3"},{"name":"X-Mailer","value":"PHPMailer (phpmailer.sourceforge.net) [version 2.0.0 rc1]"},{"name":"X-Sender","value":"ecamp@example.com"},{"name":"List-Unsubscribe","value":"<mailto:abuse+592848.6036692998@flowershopnetwork.com>, <https://www.bedfordflorist.net/ecamp/unsubscribe/5789/592848>"},{"name":"MIME-Version","value":"1.0"},{"name":"Content-Transfer-Encoding","value":"8bit"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\""}],"commonHeaders":{"from":["\"Some Gift Shop Inc.\" <noreply@example.com>"],"replyTo":["\"Some Gift Shop Inc.\" <blahblahblah@some-email.com>"],"date":"Fri, 8 Jul 2022 07:57:16 -0500","to":["some-email@yahoo.com"],"messageId":"<9d6ba9128d45561e70b162efc7b6b1b2@localhost.localdomain>","subject":"Some Subject"}}}
```

I can grab all the objects I need with the following:

```
for message in queue.receive_messages(WaitTimeSeconds=10, MaxNumberOfMessages=10):
        try:
            # Grab the json objects
            body = json.loads(message.body)
            headers = body['mail']['headers'][13]['value']
            email = body['complaint']['complainedRecipients'][0]['emailAddress']
            timestamp = body['complaint']['timestamp']
            formatted_time = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            subject = body['mail']['commonHeaders']['subject']
            region = body['mail']['sourceArn'].split(':')[3]
            ecamp_id = headers.split('|')[0]
            client_id = headers.split('|')[1]
            ecamp_source = headers.split('|')[2]
        except KeyError as e:
            print("Key Error: " + str(e))
        except IndexError as i:
            print("Index Error: " + str(i))
```

However, this other JSON is giving me problems:

```
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "99acffbc-585e-5f26-a9d0-a4da29d03df7",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:669689702539:sns-oregon-complaint-topic",
  "Message" : "{\"notificationType\":\"Complaint\",\"complaint\":{\"feedbackId\":\"010101010101010101010-blahblah\",\"complaintSubType\":null,\"complainedRecipients\":[{\"emailAddress\":\"PDKLEIN2012@YAHOO.COM\"}],\"timestamp\":\"2022-08-05T01:15:58.000Z\",\"userAgent\":\"Yahoo!-Mail-Feedback/2.0\",\"complaintFeedbackType\":\"abuse\",\"arrivalDate\":\"2022-08-05T00:51:34.000Z\"},\"mail\":{\"timestamp\":\"2022-08-05T00:51:32.988Z\",\"source\":\"noreply@example.com\",\"sourceArn\":\"arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:1234567890:identity/example.com\",\"sourceIp\":\"12.34.56.789\",\"callerIdentity\":\"mail-aws-or-1\",\"sendingAccountId\":\"123456789\",\"messageId\":\"010101826b7c6dfc-95c44e97-db49-467b-a65c-e27344874d74-000000\",\"destination\":[\"SOME-EMAIL@YAHOO.COM\"],\"headersTruncated\":false,\"headers\":[{\"name\":\"Received\",\"value\":\"from mail-aws-or-1 ([12.34.56.789]) by email-smtp.amazonaws.com with SMTP (SimpleEmailService-d-SPTLPQQAI) id 1uYbytwalUOhARFznQm0 for SOME_EMAIL@YAHOO.COM; Fri, 05 Aug 2022 00:51:32 +0000 (UTC)\"},{\"name\":\"Received\",\"value\":\"by mail-aws-or-1 (Postfix, from userid 111) id 48D951A294F; Thu,  4 Aug 2022 19:51:06 -0500 (CDT)\"},{\"name\":\"Received\",\"value\":\"from localhost.localdomain (server_name [192.168.20.2]) by mail-aws-or-1 (Postfix) with ESMTP id AEA191A2932 for <SOME_EMAIL@YAHOO.COM>; Thu,  4 Aug 2022 19:51:04 -0500 (CDT)\"},{\"name\":\"Date\",\"value\":\"Thu, 4 Aug 2022 19:51:04 -0500\"},{\"name\":\"To\",\"value\":\"SOME_EMAIL@YAHOO.COM\"},{\"name\":\"From\",\"value\":\"Some Business Name <noreply@example.com>\"},{\"name\":\"Reply-to\",\"value\":\"Some Business Name <somebusinessname@somebusinessname.com>\"},{\"name\":\"Subject\",\"value\":\"Some Subject'!\"},{\"name\":\"Message-ID\",\"value\":\"<193c811f09ad915e7857235253a06da0@localhost.localdomain>\"},{\"name\":\"X-Priority\",\"value\":\"3\"},{\"name\":\"X-Mailer\",\"value\":\"PHPMailer (phpmailer.sourceforge.net) [version 2.0.0 rc1]\"},{\"name\":\"X-Sender\",\"value\":\"ecamp@example.com\"},{\"name\":\"List-Unsubscribe\",\"value\":\"<mailto:abuse+7388957.7173542430@example.com>, <https://www.somebusinessname.com/ecamp/unsubscribe/7331/7388957>\"},{\"name\":\"Content-Description\",\"value\":\"7331|347977|SomeClassName.class\"},{\"name\":\"MIME-Version\",\"value\":\"1.0\"},{\"name\":\"Content-Transfer-Encoding\",\"value\":\"8bit\"},{\"name\":\"Content-Type\",\"value\":\"text/html; charset=\\\"iso-8859-1\\\"\"}],\"commonHeaders\":{\"from\":[\"Petal Perfect Flower Shop <noreply@example.com>\"],\"replyTo\":[\"Some Business Name <somebusinessname@somebusinessname.com>\"],\"date\":\"Thu, 4 Aug 2022 19:51:04 -0500\",\"to\":[\"SOME_EMAIL@YAHOO.COM\"],\"messageId\":\"<193c811f09ad915e7857235253a06da0@localhost.localdomain>\",\"subject\":\"Some Subject'!\"}}}",
  "Timestamp" : "2022-08-05T01:15:58.917Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "xxsdflkj0983244r098ujsadflkjlkjawe0rjoisajdf09ui234rijlksadf",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-213847068461846841354.pem",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:669689702539:sns-oregon-complaint-topic:8c681b37-39c8-40b6-8b8e-16e58ef374c2"
}
```

I'm getting `Key Error: 'mail'`

When I check the type with `print(type(body['Message'])` I'm getting `<class 'str'>`. So, in order to correctly parse these other types of messages, do I need to resort to regex? Is there a way to change this string to a dictionary so I can still access elements with `body['Message']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is your second response contains a string which contains the escaped JSON.

You should check for availability of keys which are optional. This can be done in several ways, here is one possible solution:

```
body = json.loads(message.body)
#...
if 'mail' in body :
    mail = body['mail']
#...
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898797/check-if-key-exists-and-iterate-the-json-array-using-python) mor details and other options.

To parse the escaped string, you need to load this string as JSON again:

```
message = json.loads(body['Message'])
```

Comment: 'mail' is indeed present in all messages. It's just that the structure is different. No matter what I try, I'm getting exceptions, namely `TypeError: string indices must be integers` and `KeyError 'mail'`

Comment: Got it, updated my answer.

Comment: Hey! That worked! I reloaded the `body['Message']` again and then accessed the nested items the same as before. THANK YOU SO MUCH!