# Why do i get KeyError in search_movie but not in get_movie on IMDbPY in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i wanted to get the year of the movie in IMdPY midule using `search_movie()` like this

```
import imdb

ia = imdb.IMDb()

search = ia.search_movie("The Shawshank Redemption")

year = search[0]['year']

print(search['title'] + " : " + str(year))
```

And always it gives me this ERR

```
KeyError: 'year'
```

though this err doesn't come up when i use `ia.get_movie('0133093')` (which is by searching ID)... and i dont always know the id of the movie so i want to know if there is any way i can use the `['year']` in search_movie func

Comment: What if you `print(search[0])` right before that line?  Though if you believe that `search[0]` returns "some movie" but one that may or may not have a valid `"year"` then you might check out if this helps solve things for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898797/check-if-key-exists-and-iterate-the-json-array-using-python

Comment: it print out the movie name but still get the key error

Comment: Apparently `search_movie()` must return a list of strings (movie names) not movie data...

Comment: @JonSG so how can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @JonSG and others i found a way to work on it.
the key is getting the Movie ID from search results and use that ID in `get_movie()`... since that works fine

```
import imdb

ia = imdb.IMDb()

name = "The Shawshank Redemption"
search = ia.search_movie(name)

id = search[0].movieID

search_by_id = ia.get_movie(id)
year = search_by_id['year']

print(search_by_id['title'] + " : " + str(year))
```

and the output will be

```
The Shawshank Redemption : 1994
```

**Thanks**